# In Gradle, on Android, can the Storm annotation processor be run like the AndroidAnnotations processor?

Tags: java, android, apt, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been able to successfully run AndroidAnnotations with gradle (as well as Dagger), but as soon as I attempt to add storm-apt to the generators, gradle silently fails, skipping all annotation processing.

Here is a sample build.gradle that will work (i.e run the aa apt processor, but not storm apt processor) without line containing the storm-apt jar, but will fail (i.e fail to run both the aa apt processor, as well as storm apt processor) with it:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '2.7.1'
configurations {
    apt
}

dependencies {
    apt "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    // commenting out the following line will allow the aa apt processor to complete,
    // while leaving it uncommented will cause all annotation processing, 
    // both aa and storm to silently fail
    apt files('libs/storm-apt-0.97.jar')

    compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile files('libs/storm-api-0.97.jar')
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->

        variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
            println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
            ext.aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/source/r/${variant.dirName}")
            aptOutput.mkdirs()

            aptOutput.eachFileRecurse FileType.FILES, {
                if (it.name.equals('R.java')) {
                    return
                }
                it.delete()
            }

            variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                    '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                    '-s', aptOutput
            ]

            println "*** ${variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what is failing in that code but there's a better solution now called [android-apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt) , which is a gradle plug-in.